# addValueEventListener not firing up in Android Studio using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have searched all the questions regarding this problem on Stack Overflow and I was not able to get the correct answer. The answers posted in the answer section or comment sections were not working for me. I have tried to log the values but addValueEventListener is not triggering. However, I can see the correct database reference (toString) just before the the addValueEventListener function in the logs. I have allowed all users to the database so there shouldn't be an authentication issue. I tried adding this to MainActivity.class as well but that doesn't seem to work. I have SHA1 fingerprint on the database and there is a connection to the database as well since my log.d prints the database reference child value.

Rules for my database are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null",
  }
}
```

ReadWriteActivity.class

```
package com.example.grocery;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadWriteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_write);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("names");
        Log.d("DATABASE REFERENCE", reference.toString());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot datasnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("KEY VALUE", datasnapshot.getValue().toString());
                    list.add(datasnapshot.getValue().toString());
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.w("KEY ERROR", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_read_write.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ReadWriteActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Comment: Just confirming, your security rules allow reads only when the user is NOT logged in. Is that the expected behavior ?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. The user is not logged in so my security rules allow read only@Dharmaraj

Comment: `auth == null` requires that the user is signed in. Nothing in the code you shared shows that the user is signed in, so I'd expect the `onCancelled` to get called and `Log.w("KEY ERROR", "Failed to read value."` to be logged.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

In which region did you create the Realtime Database instance, and when did you download the `google-services.json`? If it's not the US *or* if you downloaded the `google-services.json` before you created the database, the SDK won't be able to determine the correct database URL.

You have two options to fix it in that case:

1. You can specify the full database URL in the call to `getInstance()` like this: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("your database URL").getReference()`
2. You can download an updated `google-services.json` after you created the database, and make sure you app uses that file.

It's pretty easy to miss this condition right now, as the relevant warning is logged as a debug message. We're working on surfacing the message more explicitly, but in the meantime the above should also work.

Also see: [Google Firebase Real-time Database Not Working as everything is set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68173632/google-firebase-real-time-database-not-working-as-everything-is-set-correctly/68179677#68179677)

Comment: Hello, I downloaded the google.json file after adding the SDK. To recheck, I removed the older google-services.json and downloaded it again in the app folder. Both the options to fix as per your answer aren't working. I added the original url but it is not returning me the data. Please help, thank you once again!