# Fail to Write data to Firebase Realtime Database Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a Firebase, and I can write data into Authentication.
But, I could not write data into realtime database.

1. I have connected to Firebase
   [image]
2. I have add Realtime Database

```
// Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
// Declare the dependency for the Realtime Database library
// When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
```

3. I have set rules of read and write to ture

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I tried this to write data into Firebase but I get noting
[image]

```
// Write a message to the database
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
// Write a message to the database
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("aaa").child("bbb").setValue("ccc");
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("aaa").child("bbb").setValue("ccc");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for writing looks fine, so I think the problem may be elsewhere.

If you created the Firebase console *after* you downloaded the `google-services.json` file, that file will not contain the correct URL, and the SDK may not be able to find your database on the server.

To solve that problem, you can either:

- Download an updated `google-services.json` and use that in your app, or
- Provide the database URL in your code with `FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("database URL here");`

Also see: [Google Firebase Real-time Database Not Working as everything is set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68173632/google-firebase-real-time-database-not-working-as-everything-is-set-correctly/68179677#68179677)

Answer (score 1):

My code works this morning, but I did nothing except go to bed. As shown in the picture, the second step has changed. I clicked that `Add the Realtime Database SDK to your app` button thousands of times, and it was still a button. Surprisingly, it has changed to a checked state.

I did the `google-services.json` part as @FrankvanPuffelen said yesterday, but it didn't work.

I have restarted the Android Studio a lot of times and didn't work.

Maybe I should try close the computer lid next time.

But now I know that one should have the second step checked rather than keep it as a unchecked button.

[image]