# Can't write on Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write some data on my Realtime Database on Android Studio with Java.
My goal is to create and user and then add user information in Realtime Database.
I can create the User but when I'm trying to write on the Realtime Database nothing happen.
I've add a onSuccess and onFailure listener to the function that set the data, but both of th listener doesen't run.

Code:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword())
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Account creato!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                user.setUid(currentUser.getUid());
                //I add to RealTime Databse other User data
                DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                mDatabase.child("users").child("test").setValue("hey").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.i("Works","Yes");
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"It orks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Write failed
                        Log.e("ErrorAdding",e.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                //finish();

            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w("CREATEUSER", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

I'm sure the user is created because the toast with "Account creato" shows up and in firebase I can see the account added.

This is my Realtime database rules:

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",  // 2022-2-4
    ".write": "true",  // 2022-2-4
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is `user` variable defined? Why is the child data you're trying to set static for all users?

Comment: It's a parameter of this function. It's a class that contains email,password,username,uid

Comment: You should ideally define `mDatabase` outside of the user creation callback. Besides that, `mDatabase.child("users").child("test").setValue` has nothing to do with user creation, so you should debug that in isolation. For example, does it correctly write the value on just a button click?

Comment: @OneCricketeer so I've tried it and it has the same previous behaviour. I've added a failure listener and it does nothing

Comment: Does `users/test`path exist in the database?

Comment: @OneCricketeer No, I can't add empty field in realtime database. Does it work like firestore database where you can put the path and if it doesen't exist, it will make the missing folders?

Comment: Paths are overwritten, if they exist, but if there's nothing there, shouldn't be a problem. Is there a specific reason you're using `"test"` rather than the user ID, as shown in the docs? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes because at first I was using uid but it didn't work and for trying to see what was wrong I tryied a static path for check if it was the writing on Realtime database the problem

Comment: If neither of the callbacks fires, it typically means the client is not connected to the database server. Can you check the logcat output for messages when you call `setValue` (or otherwise when you first access the database)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've cheked the logcat when pressing the button but I don't see any message regarding the setValue or firebase

Comment: Is any of the Toast messages displayed?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so I added a value on the database manually and I tried to read it. I get this error: E/firebase: Error getting data
    java.lang.Exception: Client is offline . But I can create accounts on firestore so I don't know why it gives this error

Comment: My guess is that you downloaded the `google-services.json` file before the database was created, which means the database URL that the SDK uses is incorrect. If that is indeed the cause, download the updated `google-services.json` and add it to your project, **or** put the database URL in your code in `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("URL to your databse here").getReference()`. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69198094

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, now I've changed the google-services.json with the new and inside the file I see the correct url to the database, but when in my application I try to log print it, it is still the previous one

Comment: EDIT: I've cleaned and rebuilt my Android project and now it gives me the correct url. Now it works thanks