# Why is my method not setting a new value in realtime database?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want the user to get a specified amount (500) of money (int) once they get registered into the system with Firebase Auth. The email (with a , instead of a .) is taken from the input of the user which will be the userid (child) in realtime database. And the money should be the child of userid.

I tried it with my  `writeNewUserMoney` method:
[realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Ku8.png)

I tried it with my  `writeNewUserMoney` method:

```java
public void writeNewUserMoney() {
    String email = encodeUserEmail(signupEmail.getText().toString().trim());
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabaseReference.child("user").child(email).setValue(500);
}
```

Here is `encodeUserEmail`:

```java
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}
```

Here is the relevant part of the class:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String user = signupEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass = signupPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    if (user.isEmpty()){
        signupEmail.setError("Email eingeben");
    }
    if (pass.isEmpty()){
        signupPassword.setError("Passwort eingeben");
    } else{
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new                         OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "SignUp Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "SignUp Failed" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        });
    }
//
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser kuser = auth.getCurrentUser();
    //bestätigungs mail
    kuser.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("Email sent");
                }
            }
    });
    //bestätigungs mail
    //Kontoinstandsetzung
    writeNewUserMoney();
}
```

The database doesn't change when initiating an onClick.
I already tried this : [Fail to Write data to Firebase Realtime Database Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197762/fail-to-write-data-to-firebase-realtime-database-android)

If you know any other methods to assign a value in realtime database after the or with reg without the user seeing it, feel free to comment.

[The Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XVad.png)

Comment: I don't immediately see what's going wrong in the code. You might want to [add a completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) to your `setValue` call to see if it raises any error. --- If that doesn't show anything: is there any other place in your code where you access the database that *does* work? If not, you might want to try a simpler `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Test").setValue(true)` call. If that also doesn't work, it may be that your database URL is not set correctly.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen van Puffelen, used a completion listener and it turns out it get never got completed. I found this error: Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to--  but i already choose my region ( eu- west). I added a picture of it in my question

Comment: Read it wrong: I habe to change the URL, you were right @Frank van Puffelen. Thank you