# Can't write data to firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a new android studio project in java and followed the firebase realtime database tutorial and setup from the firebase documentation. I tried everything, even recreated the project, but no value seems to be written to the realtime database. I don't know what to do.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.firebase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Write a message to the database
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
        Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: " + myRef.toString());
        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
        // DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
        // myRef.child("message").setValue("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Firebase security rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    // ".read": "now < 1705276800000",  // 2024-1-15
    ".read": true,
    // ".write": "now < 1705276800000",  // 2024-1-15
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

This is how my firebase realtime database looks (I put the value there manually):
[image: firebase realtime database screenshot]

The app runs and no error is thrown to the console, so I don't think the problem is with the dependencies.

Added the following to MainActivity

```
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!").addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: " + "Success");
}).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: " + e.getMessage());
});
```

Logcat displays nothing useful
[image]

Comment: You're not checking the result of setValue.  It could be generating an error and you've never know. See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback).

Comment: I tried it, couldn't get more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If neither the success nor the failure listener fires, the app is likely not connected to the server. If your network connection is good, this might be caused by a missing configuration in your `google-services.json` file - which won't contain the database URL if you downloaded it before creating a database.

The two options to address this:

- Re-download the `google-services.json` file from the Firebase console, and rebuild your Android app with this updated file.
- Specify the database URL in your code here:

  ```
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("your database URL here");
  ```

Also see:

- [Google Firebase Real-time Database Not Working as everything is set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68173632/google-firebase-real-time-database-not-working-as-everything-is-set-correctly/68179677#68179677)
- [Fail to Write data to Firebase Realtime Database Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197762/fail-to-write-data-to-firebase-realtime-database-android/69198094#69198094)
- [unable to connect to firebase realtime database andriod studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71286781/unable-to-connect-to-firebase-realtime-database-andriod-studio/71286828#71286828)
- [Firebase Authenticated but not storing in real time database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72252980/firebase-authenticated-but-not-storing-in-real-time-database/72252991#72252991)

Comment: This solves it, although it seems completely logical, the documentation didn't point it out clearly.