# No write to database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

Trying to use Firebase Realtime Database. I have :

```
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;
```

In `onCreate` of main activity I'm trying to write record:

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("settings");
mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue("aaaa").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Data written successfully");
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Failed with: " + task.getException().getMessage());
            }
        }

    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        Log.d("TAG", "Failed with: " + e.getMessage()); });
```

But still have NULL in the Firebase console in the DB browser.

`build.gradle` has lines:

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.2"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0")
```

What did I do wrong?

UPD

Changed code by adding `onComplete` and `OnFailure` listeners.
None of events are called.

Comment: Just to have this out of the way and that is probably not the problem: Do you have the correct database rules, that you are actually allowed to write data?

Comment: `setValue` can fail.  You're not checking the result for errors.

Comment: To detect the failures Doug talks about, you can add a completion listener as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback

Comment: The the completion listener is not called, the client likely can't reach the server. The most common cause of that these days is that you downloaded the `google-services.json` file before you created the database, so the file doesn't contain its URL. If that is the case, you can either re-download the file and rebuild the app with it, or you can specify the URL in your code: `mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("your full database URL here");`. For more on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68179677

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field declarations and the way you are setting the data look good to me. However, the dependencies that exist inside your `build.gradle` file should follow the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android). So when using BOM, there is no need to specify the version of the Realtime Database. So the dependencies should look like this:

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.2"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
//
```

Since we cannot see your rules, there might be however some issues. So first of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, you should log the error message if `task` is not successful. So in code, it should look like this:

```
mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue("aaaa").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Data written successfully");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed with: " + task.getException().getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Changed code by adding onComplete and OnFailure listeners. None of events are called. More info in question body UPD

Comment: Ok, then have you tried FrankvanPuffelen's recommendation in the last comment? Does it work if do that operation?